# Why am I getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' error in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new to this NodeJS. I am trying to run a text on terminal. I am getting the text but at the same time an error is appended to it i.e., SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. I don't know why it is coming.

app.js

```
const getnotes = require('./notes.js')
console.log('check3')

getnotes()
```

notes.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
console.log('check1')
fs.writeFileSync('notes.txt', 'Hello, my name is Abc.')
console.log('check2')
const getnotes = function (){
    return require('./notes.txt')
}
module.exports = getnotes
```

I expect 
`Hello, my name is Abc.`

but I am getting

```
check1
check2
check3
C:\Users\Raja Naveen\Desktop\node-course\notes-app\notes.txt:1
Hello, my name is Abc.
          ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at getnotes (C:\Users\Raja Naveen\Desktop\node-course\notes-app\notes.js:8:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Raja Naveen\Desktop\node-course\notes-app\app.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
```

Comment: You should include complete source code in your question, not just fragments you think are appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't `require` txt files, and we use a semicolon to terminate a statement.

Read the file with a file reader instead.

```
 fs.readFileSync('notes.txt', 'utf-8');
                                      ^ semicolon
```

---

Note that use of syncronous file api is discouraged, read the docs.

Comment: Yeah!! that worked. Thanks but got sometime to understand it clearly :)